# Does possible autocorrelation in data affect simple correlations?

Tags: autocorrelation, cross-correlation

I have a question concerning autocorrelation in data affecting correlation coefficients. Consider a time series of stock returns (e.g. 10 trading days) of different stock markets (A, B, C and D) and I just want to calculate simple correlation coefficients (let it be Pearson's) for each pair of stock markets (AB, AC, ...). A paper I read therefore estimated returns via a VAR framework to control for serial correlation and computed afterwards the correlations.

Regarding to literature stock returns are often affected by autocorrelation and therefore should be controlled. As I'm not familiar with time series, I read a little bit about it and found, that autocorrelation causes problems for estimating OLS coefficient causing them to be inefficient.

My question is now, does it have any consequences if I just use my observations (without any adjustment for autocorrelation) and do the simple correlation calculations, because I won't estimate anything with it afterwards?

Comment: It may help you to read my answer here: [Usual regression vs. regression when variables are differenced](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19630/7290).

Comment: So in fact it would be useful to test for a unit root first and, if one is detected, to fix that via differencing. Afterwards, check for a linear time trend and fix if needed by detrending and then compute correlation coefficients? Did I understood this correctly?