# Use of z-score to normalize two different datasets (price and volume) for comparison

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, normalization

**Background:**

I'm trying to look at the correlation between two datasets, one consisting of price and the other of volume, for a commodity over a period of time. The data are not normally distributed. The price and volume have very different means and standard deviations.

Since I'm interested in how differences in volume affect differences in price, I created another dataset of the daily changes in price and volume. These daily changes are what I am trying to look at.

To do this, I've normalized the daily changes in price and volume data. The reason for this is to be better able to visualize the changes with the same y-axis. The results weren't great (see figure attached below) because the volume is a lot more volatile, so I will probably go with a secondary y axis to compare.

**Questions:**

1. Is it technically correct to use z-scores in this type of comparison between two different datasets, or are there better ways to compare daily differences between two different datasets?
2. And if I would like to look at the overall measure of correlation between price and volume, what form of hypothesis testing would I use? Note: both large negative and positive price changes result in spikes of volume. Is there a suitable testing method for this circumstance?

EDIT: Added more info, updated graph (originally attached incorrect graph)
[image: z-scores of differences in price & volume over a period of time]

Comment: You wouldn't use a transformation & a normal correlation (eg, see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19630/7290)). You need to use time-series methods. I don't know that material, but I think you may need [tag:garch].

Comment: @gung: Why shouldn't I use normal correlation? I feel that it would still give useful information over a short period of time (<80-90 days).

Comment: You don't use a correlation with time series. That's covered lots of places. 1 that I can think of is my answer linked above. Someone who's more expert on the topic will give you a better answer.

Comment: @gung: Based off of the linked answer, it looks like you cannot use correlation with time series, but using correlation of differences on time series data can be useful (your example is x vs y1 and x vs y2). Anyways, thank you for the guidance, I will read about garch now.

Comment: Differencing may (or may not) be what you need. The series should be stationary, for which differencing may or may not be the right approach (cf @Charlie's [answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19646/7290)). It's slow now, but someone will help with this in time.